# Why might starting a YARN NodeManager throw a KosmosFileSystem FileSystem exception?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to start a YARN NodeManager on my CDH 5.2.0 cluster using Cloudera Manager. All the other live nodes in the system started fine with the configuration in Cloudera Manager, but one node refuses to start, and throws this exception when started:

```
2015-01-09 04:12:17,619 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the KosmosFileSystem FileSystem implementation
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(FileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartRecoveryStore(NodeManager.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:492)
```

This doesn't make any sense to me at all: why would the thing be trying to initialize this unheard-of file system, let alone perform operations on it, when booting? It looks like this is during NodeManager recovery, (`initAndStartRecoveryStore`), so I tried deleting the `yarn.nodemanager.recovery.dir` on that node to see if it might make a difference, which it didn't.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the KosmosFileSystem FileSystem implementation
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!msg/cdh-user/GJINA22DL5Q/xM4k2yCpftgJ

Comment: I don't think thats my problem. This issue occurs during NodeManager boot up before any jobs have been accepted by it, let alone MapReduce 1 jobs which I am not running on YARN :) Thanks for the link though!